# GROUP BY Create group if at least one value in group meets condition

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, group-by

How to create group if at least one value in group meets condition?

Here is an example of DB table `test`:

```
| ID | TYPE | COLOR |
|====|======|=======|
|  1 |    1 |     R |
|  2 |    1 |     B |
|  3 |    1 |     G |
|  4 |    2 |     B |
|  5 |    2 |     G |
|  6 |    3 |     G |
```

I need to select all `TYPE` values that have more than one row, and at least one of COLORs is G for that TYPE.

So pseudo-select would look like this:

```
  select TYPE 
    from test
group by TYPE
  having count(*) > 1
     and count(COLOR = 'G') > 0
```

Comment: Is NULL possible in the COLOR column? Can there be duplicate colors for the same TYPE? And what version of Oracle do you use?

Comment: @mathguy , NULL is not possible in COLOR column, duplicate values in COLOR column are possible for the same value in TYPE column. Also made correction of the question "all TYPE that have more than one COLOR and at least one of them is G" is changed to "all TYPE values that have more than one row, and at least one of COLORs is G for that TYPE"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the OP's modified requirement:

```
select   type
from     test
group by type
having   count(*) > 1 and count(case when color = 'G' then 0 end) > 0
;
```

Comment: Hm... It works fine but why the clause is not **case when color = 'G' then 1 else 0 end**? And how is it working in your case? If color is G case statement returns 0 and it is counted as +1, if color is not G case statement returns NULL, so it is not counted, right?

Comment: If I am using **case when color = 'G' then 1 else 0 end** then there should be another agregate function **sum(case when color = 'G' then 1 else 0 end) > 0**, right?

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko - the condition is not **case when ...** - it is **COUNT(case when....)**. Don't leave out the COUNT. COUNT counts all non-NULL values and DOES NOT CARE what those non-NULL values are; it does not add them up, it just counts them. This is very different from **SUM(case when....)**. In the **COUNT(...)** approach I don't even need to use numbers; the same will work equally well with `count(case when color = 'G' then 'x' end)`. The point is EXACTLY to NOT have an `else` part of the `case` expression with a non-NULL value assigned when the color is not `G`.

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko - with COUNT, I could even do `count(case when color = 'G' then SYSDATE end)`. The `case` expression now has DATE data type. It doesn't matter; the value will be non-NULL for color 'G' and NULL otherwise, and that is all that COUNT cares about. You couldn't assign character or date values in the CASE expression if you used **SUM(CASE....)** but with **COUNT** you can.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a inner join  on th count(color)

```
 select t1.type 
 from test  t1
 inner join (
     select type, count(color)
     from test
     where  type in (select  type from test where color='G' )
     group by type
 ) t2 on t1.type = t2.type
 group by t1.type 
 having count(*) > 1
```

or  in a simplest way

```
   select t1.type 
   from test  t1
   inner join  test t2 on t1.type = t2.type and t2.color = 'G'
   group by t1.type 
   having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: No need for joins, a single aggregate query should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

`count` only counts non-`null` values. A neat trick to wrap both required conditions into one is to count the distinct number of a case expression that returns something for `G` and something else for any other value:

```
SELECT   type
FROM     test
GROUP BY type
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE color WHEN 'G' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) = 2
```

Comment: This is almost right. You need to add a condition in the HAVING clause to check also that `count(case when color != 'G' then 1 end) > 0` to implement the OP's requirement in its entirety.

Comment: @mathguy wow, missed that completely, thanks. See my edited answer for a neat trick to wrap both conditions into one.

Comment: :-)  That is how I would have written it too. Or perhaps (to avoid DISTINCT) - `max(case...) != min(case...)`